# Unity Default.ruleset Doesnt Work As Expected / Roslyn Analyzer

Tags: unity-game-engine, roslyn, rider, roslyn-code-analysis, jetbrains-rider

[Roslyn analyzers and source generators](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/roslyn-analyzers.html#analyser-scope-anchor-link)

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxjD1.png)

[Actual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iAe6xBa_oLfhFzS8RFBNm6CkN8ivWty9/view?usp=sharing)

Unity 2021.3.11f1 / Rider 2022.2.3

Analyzers: ErrorProne.NET.CoreAnalyzers

Only logging Assets\Subfolder\RethrowError's error. When I remove the subfolders code then logs the Assets\Rethrow's  error.

And if I add new subfolder then logs two of them subfolder's error as expected. But still doesnt log the base folder's error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> In the Assets root folder, place a ruleset file named Default.ruleset. The rules you define in Default.ruleset apply to all predefined assemblies (for example Assembly-CSharp.dll), and all assemblies that are built using .asmdef files.
> ***Source:** https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/roslyn-analyzers.html*

Your setup is correct and both scripts should be affected by your `Default.ruleset`.

I'm struggling with the same issue and added a post to that thread asking for help:

- https://forum.unity.com/threads/exclude-unity-packages-from-roslyn-analyzers.1164572/#post-8529479